# Cant get a Access Code for Instagram Access Token

Tags: instagram, access-token

I made a homepage for a friend, i create a API Instagram Application.
I tested everything with my Access Token and it worked. Then I send him the link for the authorization like this

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[MY CLIENTID!!!]&redirect_uri=[MY URL!!!]&response_type=code
```

For me it worked to get the code to generate the Access Token, but when he opens the link, he get the error .... NOT A SANDBOX USER! I added him as Sandbox User but it doesnt works :(

What can i do? Greetings